# wpf datagrid: dynamically change combobox collection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I have a datagrid with Product ,Serial No columns respectively where SerialNo is a DatagridComboboxColumn.I want to populate the serial no combobox When the Product is selected as dynamically based on the product Id.
My Xaml is:

```
 <my:DataGrid Name="dgSales" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionUnit="Cell"   AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
      <my:DataGrid.Columns>
<my:DataGridTextColumn  Header="Product" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding ProductName}"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
<my:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Serial No" Width="135"
                                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SerialNo}"
                                                SelectedValuePath="SlRecord_Id"
                                                DisplayMemberPath="SlNum"

                                               >
  <my:DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding}" />
                            </Style>
  </my:DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
  <my:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding}" />

                            </Style>
                        </my:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    </my:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
  </my:DataGrid.Columns>
</my:DataGrid>
```

My DataObject is :

```
 class clsSalesItems : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
     private string _ProductName;
     private string _SerialNo;
      private ObservableCollection<ModelNos> _SerialNos;


   public string ProductName
    {
        get { return _ProductName; }
        set
        {
            _ProductName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductName");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ModelNos> SerialNos
    {
        get
        {
            return _SerialNos; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            _SerialNos = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SerialNos");
        }
    }
}
```

My SerialNo class is:

```
 public class ModelNos
{
    private int _SlRecord_Id;
    private string _SlNo;

    public int SlRecord_Id
    {
        get { return _SlRecord_Id; }
        set
        {
            _SlRecord_Id = value;
        }
    }
    public string SlNum
    {
        get { return _SlNo; }
        set
        {
            _SlNo = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is I want to populate the Serial no combobox column when the product is selected dynamically(serial no is different for each product).How do I Bind the Serial no combobox when the Product selected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to SelectedItem property of the DataGrid or better said bind that property to a property in your ViewModel. When you select a row in your DataGrid your setter of the property in ViewModel will be called and there you may check the new value and based on it you may set SerialNos property. Once you set SerialNos the PropertyChanged event will be fired which will tell DataGrid that the ItemsSource of the ComboBox has been refreshed. DataGrid will futhermore populate the ComboBoxes with new values.

Its pure View-ViewModel-Model pattern. Such problems shall be solved just by using MVVM and not catching some events in view and handling them in code behind.